# UIButton and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a UIScrollView that contains a long image, whose height is way more than a screen could hold at the current time. Now I want to place buttons all over the image. However, some of the buttons are below the view that you see when you haven't scrolled yet and after scrolling to the bottom of the image, the button I currently press is the one at the top that occupies the position of the screen itself when one hasn't scrolled yet. In short, not the button at the bottom is clicked when I scroll down and click on it, but the one at the top. How do I solve this? Note: my code is in Swift, so please write down code snippets in Swift and not Objective-C.

```
func makeImage(){

    //might change the following to make it more dynamic later on


    imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:brand.name + "-" + genderChoice.name + "-"+generalOverviewChoice.name+"-Detail.png"))

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)

    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, imageView.frame.size.height/2)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375,imageView.frame.size.height)

    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

func createButton(button: UIButton,x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){

    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "btnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code. Also make sure you have each button linked to its own function(check you have not linked all to same). Without any code posted I can only guess though.

Comment: see Update. I have makeImage() that creates a scrollview and image view and I have createButton. Here, I pass in for example x: 2000, which is way down the screen. Result->Button is sadly not created properly.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, can you please rewrite your question. But if the problem is that your buttons do not position themselves correctly try adding them to "imageView" or "scrollView" instead of "self.view". Again I am having a hard time understanding your question. Also, where do you call "createButton()" + "makeImage()"?